# Recursive function runs infinitely even after having a base case

Tags: python, function, recursion

```
count = 5
def countdown(count):
    print(count)
    count = count - 1
    while count > 0:
     countdown(count)
    if count<=0:
        return

countdown(count)
```

I am trying to understand the basics of recursion. When I run this function, the function runs infinitely printing the count value as 1. However, the desired output should be 54321. Is there something wrong with my while loop condition?

Comment: Change `while` to `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use:

```
while count > 0:
     countdown(count)
```

What's the point of iteration aka while loop in recursion?
This causes the following problem: count is reduced inside countdown but when the call returns the count variable is unchanged due to the fact that python uses by value parameter passing.

Apart from that it is commonly used to have the base case in the beginning. All this result in the following code:

```
count = 5
def countdown(count):
    if count==0:
        return
    print(count)
    countdown(count-1)


countdown(count)
```